# Как установить библиотеку openssl

Tags: c++, openssl, nasm

Устанавливаю openssl(версия 1.1.0f) под windows 10(64) для с++ VS 2017 community следующим образом(согласно описанному алгоритму установки в файле INSTALL) через "x64 native tools command prompt for vs 2017":

```
$ perl Configure VC-WIN64A 
$ nmake
$ nmake test
$ nmake install
```

но после ввода первой команды `$ perl Configure VC-WIN64A` возникает следующая ошибка:

> NASM not found - please read INSTALL and NOTES.WIN for further details

погуглив понял что необходимо установить NASM, а также прописать в переменную среды адрес к директории, что я и сделал(NASM установил версии 2.13.01), но результат ввода первой команды не изменился.
Попробовал тоже самое через perl, эта команда сработала, следующая нет. 
Не могу понять, сколько форумов просмотрел, нигде нет конкретики, взять хотя бы вот эту [статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/277935/), описано все ОК, но повторяя тоже самое, возникает масса ошибок.

Comment: Могли бы вы указать ссылку, не могу найти

Comment: @Abyx Отпишитесь в ответ, отмечу